# Не везде работает скрипт

Tags: jquery

Доброго времени суток!

Есть скрипт

```
jQuery(this).click(function () {
    $("#exampleMenu").animate({
        top: '-600px'
    }, 600, "linear");
});
```

Он срабатывает в хроме, но не работает в опере. Подскажите, в чем может быть дело?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Третий аргумент метода `.animate()` — функция, срабатывающая после выполнения анимации. Она задаётся либо так:

```
$("#exampleMenu").animate(a,b,c);
```

Или же её можно вызвать, задав прежде:

```
function linear()
    {
        //тело функции
    }
$("#exampleMenu").animate(a,b,'linear');
```

Видимо, функция `linear` — какая-то из стандартных функций, заданых в Хроме, либо в какой-то из его js-библиотек.